# Changing Background Color of drawRect

Tags: ios, drawing, drawrect

I have drawn a line using `drawRect:` in a file called 'LineView.m'.

In another file called 'ViewController.m' I am creating a 'else if' statement.  When this statement is called it will change the color of the `drawRect:`. But how should I write something that does that?

I found an example for other objects like views, backgrounds, etc.

```
 self.box.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

But this will not work on the `drawRect` because I need to put something where 'box' is, that will identify the drawRect. But what?

Can I name my `drawRect:` and use the name to identify it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIColor property in LineView.h called like lineColor. In LineView.m override the default setter of lineColor like so:

```
-(void)setLineColor:(UIColor *)lineColor
{
    _lineColor = lineColor;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Then in drawRect before you draw the line say:

```
[self.lineColor setStroke];
```

Now you can set the line color like so:

```
self.lineView.lineColor = [UIColor redColor/* or whatever you want*/];
```

EDIT: I misread your question the above will change the color of the line. To change the background, say something like `self.lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor someColor];` where lineView is whatever you're calling the instance of the LineView object.